# Many-to-many in Cassandra 3

Tags: cassandra, many-to-many, cql, cassandra-3.0

What's the right way to model many-to-many relationships in Cassandra (using 3.10 at the moment)?

From what answers I was able to find, denormalization into two relationship tables is suggested (as in here, for example: [Modeling many-to-many relations in Cassandra 2 with CQL3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573243/modeling-many-to-many-relations-in-cassandra-2-with-cql3)). But there are problems with that on deletes, and those answers are so sparse they do not mention any details on that.

Suppose we have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE bar (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
  foo UUID,
  bar UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (foo, bar)
)
CREATE TABLE bar_foo (
  bar UUID,
  foo UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (bar, foo)
)
```

This seems to be the suggested answer. However, what happens when we try deleting a `bar` record? Updating the `bar_foo` table is easy:

```
DELETE FROM bar_foo WHERE bar = <bar_key>
```

However, an attempt to update the `foo_bar` table fails:

```
DELETE FROM foo_bar WHERE bar = <bar_key>
```

with the following error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some partition key parts are missing: foo"
```

This is because the primary key for the `foo_bar` table is `(foo, bar)`, and we specify only the second part of the primary key in the WHERE clause of the DELETE statement. Cassandra, apparently, requires a prefix of the primary key, and `bar` without `foo` is not a prefix.

Now, changing the primary key to `(bar, foo)` won't help. After all, what would you do, then, if a `foo` record gets deleted? And, in any case, the entire purpose of the `foo_bar` table is to be able to find all `bar` records corresponding to a given `foo` record, and a SELECT statement *also* requires a prefix of the primary key in the WHERE clause (which must, by necessity, be `foo`).

Can't do SELECT and then DELETE, either, since a SELECT by `bar` won't work, it not being a prefix of the primary key.

So what to do with many-to-many relationships, when deletes are in the picture? Is this even possible to accomplish properly?

Comment: you can create materialized view and cassandra will take care of it... for bar_foo and foo_bar kind of scenario

Comment: Oh, Cassandra 3 has materialized views. Good! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE bar (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
  foo UUID,
  bar UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (foo, bar)
)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW bar_foo AS
  SELECT bar, foo FROM foo_bar
    WHERE foo IS NOT NULL AND bar IS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (bar, foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSet.html

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE bar (
  key UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  content TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE foo_jn_bar (
  foo UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  bar set<UUID>
)
CREATE TABLE bar_jn_jn (
  bar UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  foo set<UUID>
)
```

If you follow the relational habit, you will have huge duplicity in disk data.