# Manage many to many relationship in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have these two tables:

```
create table users (
    id UUID,
    email ascii,
    created_at timeuuid,
    primary key(id, email)
);
create table groups (
    id UUID,
    name ascii,
    created_at timeuuid,
    primary key(id, name)
);
```

> A user can be in multiple groups, a group can obviously have multiple users.

So I've two ways to maintain a many-to-many relationship (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550900/many-to-many-in-cassandra-3)), one is:

```
CREATE TABLE user_group (
  user UUID,
  group UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (user, group)
)
```

Another one is (using sets):

```
CREATE TABLE user_jn_group (
  user UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  groups set<UUID>
)
CREATE TABLE group_jn_user (
  group UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  users set<UUID>
)
```

I'm using Cassandra 3.9.0. I know both approaches have their own advantages, disadvantages. I want the least duplicity, but also I have an equal weight to read/write speed. Also, is there any more hidden cost behind any of both approaches?

Comment: Do you have a use-case for querying all users in a given group?

Comment: um, yeah for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using collections for this is probably impractical because of the size limit on collections (although that shouldn't be a concern for a system with just a few users), chances are high that the set of users in a group will be too large.

It's also worth noting that your solution based on the `user_group` table won't work as it won't support querying by group. You would need to maintain ***another*** table to support this query (and always maintain the two records):

```
CREATE TABLE group_user (
  user UUID,
  group UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY (group, user)
)
```

This will allow querying by group.

---

Additional options:

**Add a secondary index to `user_group`**:

Another approach is to expand the `user_group` solution: if you have a secondary index on the `group` field, you'll be able to perform lookups in both ways:

```
CREATE INDEX ON user_group (group);
```

**Use a materialized view**

You can also use a materialized view instead of a `group_user` table. The data between `user_group` and this view will be kept in sync by cassandra (eventually):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW group_user
AS SELECT group, user
FROM user_group
WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND group IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (group, user);
```

With this, you'll have to add a record to `user_group` only and the view will take care of searches by group.

As you noted, each has pros and cons that can't be detailed here. Please check the docs on limitations of each option.